# Unexpected username on questions tab (last action) in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, questions

I can see who did the last action on my question in the questions tab on my page (as I understand it).

[image: picture: 16 hours ago lucumt]

To my surprise, I see the username of a user that has nothing to do with my question, at least according to [the timeline of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51195140/timeline).

[image: picture: the timeline of this question]

So, what can this action be? Answering and deleting answer or something else?

Is it normal that the questions tab shows an action that isn't shown anywhere else?

Comment: "Answering and deleting answer" <- this

Comment: Since answers can be edited while they're deleted, bumping them to the top of active list is expected (so users can review the answer). How do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you had 10K rep you'd see a more complete [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51195140/timeline) showing you that an answer was added and then deleted, although with 10K you can also see the deleted answer directly.

[image]